Maase Miriam on the way of leaving Egypt?
The Torah in this week's Parsha tells us on Deut.24:9 to remember what Hashem did to Miriam on the way of getting out of Egypt.
I looked at the most commentaries from the Rishonim and could not find an answer to the following question: why does the Torah stresses out "on the way of getting out of Egypt"? Seemingly this verse is referring to what happened to Miriam, end of Parshat Behaalotcha, nearly one year after camping at the foot of Mount Sinai. Is that still considered Egypt?

The answer is given in Midrash Sifrei Devarim 275:2-3:

בדרך, בשעת טירופכם
on the way: when you were tossed about.
בצאתכם ממצרים, בשעת גאולתכם אלא שתלה הכתוב במרים ללמדך שכל זמן שהיו הדגלים נוסעים לא היו הולכים עד שמרים מקדמת לפניהם וכן הוא אומר (מיכה ו ד) ואשלח לפניך את משה אהרן ומרים סליק פיסקא
when you left Egypt: the time of your redemption, and all was stopped because of her, whereby we are apprised that all of that time when the standards of the tribes traveled, they did so only when Miriam preceded them, viz. (Michah 6:4) "In fact, I brought you up from the land of Egypt, I redeemed you from the house of bondage, And I sent before you Moses, Aaron, and Miriam."

In other words, the time of geula, based on the verse in Micha, is called "getting out of Mitzraim" (physically and spiritually), and it was marked by Moshe, Aharon, and Miriam leading Jewish people. However, because of Miriam's punishment, the whole travel was halted and everyone had to wait for her.
